# _maxListeners:10 in Redis. What does that mean for sub/pub?

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I am working on a real-time webapp with Redis as storage & pub/sub.
When I took a closer look at my Redis db (default options) this particular value confused me.

What does this value mean for my pub/sub app? 
Can it only handle 10 simultaneous connections and if so, can I change the number?

Looking at the documentation for https://github.com/mranney/node_redis and the options I can change didn't give any straight answers.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: _maxListeners isn't a real maximum, it's the max you can create before node will issue a warning that you might be leaking listeners.  See http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

Comment: @generalhenry is right, but "listeners" here means local listeners on the EventEmitter/Redis javascript object (e.g. too many `redis.on('message', ...)` lines), not subscribers in Redis itself.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer!